# Remove bootmgr from second disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootmgr

I recently reinstalled windows 7 on ssd, but the installer put the boot files on hdd. Managed to fix this, with bcdedit and copy boot files to ssd. But now I have extra 'boot' folder and 'bootmgr' on hdd. How can I remove them without reformat?

The only active partition is the ssd. hdd set inactive, and windows able to boot without hdd connected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not using that boot folder ? you can check by disabling that hard drive on bios and try to boot... if it boots you can delete that folder...

First you have to get permissions on the folder so you can delete it... thats what I just did... it worked...